# Querying a complex JSON Schema with mongoengine

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2, mongoengine

I am trying to build a webapp with flask and mongoengine, but get stuck with the following problem.

Assume there is a document with JSON structure like this:

```
"user": {
  "value": "username",
  [...]
},
"entities": [
  {
    "key": "foo",
    "value": "123"
  }, 
    "key": "bar",
    "value": "456"
  },
  [...]
]
```

1)
First I want to get the whole document from user "username", I tried:

```
userdata = models.User.objects(user__match = {"value": "username"})
```

but this return an empty doc. I also tried something like this:

```
userdata = models.User.objects(user__contains = "username")
```

But then I got: 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

I read the docs, and sneaked around but found nothing helpful.

2)
When the document got (finally) from the DB, I need to catch all the `value`s from the `entities` for displaying that within an jinja2 template, but have no clue how to managed that.

This is (part of) the model:

```
class Username(EmbeddedDocument):
    value = StringField(
        primary_key = True,
        unique = True)
    created = DateTimeField(
        require = True,
        default = datetime.utcnow())

class Entities(EmbeddedDocument):
    etype = StringField(
        require = True,
        choices = ENTITYTYPES)
    key = StringField(
        require = True,
        choices = ENTITIES)
    value = StringField(
        require = True)
    modiefied = DateTimeField(
        require = True,
        default = datetime.utcnow())

class User(Document):
    user = EmbeddedDocumentField(
        Username)
    entities = ListField(
        GenericEmbeddedDocumentField(Entities))
```

As mentioned from @Paul I tried some queries:

```
userdata = models.User.objects.get(entities={"key": "foo"})
```

Result: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_mongo'`

```
userdata = models.User.objects(entities={"key": "foo"})
```

Result: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_mongo'`

```
userdata = models.User.objects(user__entities = {"key": "foo"})
```

Result: `mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "user"`

```
userdata = models.User.objects.get(entities={"key": "foo"})
```

Result: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_mongo'`

```
userdata = models.User.objects(__raw__={"key": "foo"})
```

Result: `[]`

```
userdata = models.User.objects(key='foo')
```

Result: `mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "key"`

Comment: post your User class code and the source of JSON at the top of your question.

Comment: added model, queries and reseults

Answer (score 2):

While further searching around, I came across [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261759/mongodb-search-for-each-dict-in-list-in-collection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360423/getting-a-dictionary-inside-a-list-by-key-in-mongodb-mongoengine).

Putting them together brought this answer for my first question:
`data = models.User.objects(__raw__ = { 'user.value': 'username' })`

So I get the data from the user. To sort it out in jinja2, I found that [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/list-of-dictionary-in-jinja-template) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141073/rendering-a-python-dict-in-jinja2-werkzeug) and so I came to this template:

```
{% for dict_item in data %}
  {% for item in dict_item['entities'] %}
    <h1>Key: {{item['key']}}</h1>
    <h2>Value: {{item['value']}}</h2>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Just for documentation: If you need to print your mongoengine query in the shell, use this:

```
from bson import json_util
objects = models.User.objects.all()
json_util.dumps(objects._collection_obj.find(objects._query))
```

Answer (score 0):

Am i right, that Model `User` has a field `user`, and that field is a dict?
What if you try this:

```
userdata = models.User.objects.get(user={"value": "username"}) # will return one
userdata = models.User.objects(user={"value": "username"})     # will return multiple
```

Or this:

```
userdata = models.User.objects(user__user = {"value": "username"})
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. But it is not working :-(  

`models.User.objects.get(..)` brings up `app.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.`  

`models.User.objects(...)` is an empty result set  

`models.User.objects(user__user = (...))` generate 
`mongoengine.errors.InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "user"`  

This stuff drives me crazy :)